# AFNetworking 2.x JSON POST Data Empty on Server

Tags: php, ios, json, ipad, afnetworking-2

I was using AFNetworking 1.x, and I'm trying to switch to 2.x. However, what was working fine, is now broken. I subclassed the AFHTTPRequestOperationManager, and this is the code in one of my methods in that subclass:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [self POST:@"api.php" parameters:self.requestPOST success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    //success code here
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    //failure code here
}];
```

In my init method for my subclass, I've set the baseURL and the following:

```
self.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
self.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
```

When this runs, it does successfully reach the server, and the server sends a response. However, the server is showing that the $_POST, $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA, and php://input are all empty. I check the NSURLRequest body data before it's sent, and it's filled properly with the JSON data.

Any ideas why the POST data is showing as empty when it reaches the server?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know but I can provide you code which I use

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

```
manager.responseSerializer =  [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];

//    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes =  [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];
[manager POST:urlStr parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
 {
     NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:nil];
    success(dict);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    failure(error);
}];
```

Try this code.Let me know if issue doesnt resolve..!